# Is it correct to say "The mom should lie outside and the little kid inside because the kid often tosses around in his sleep and fall off the bed"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

I have a bed and 1 long side of the bed comes in contact with the wall.

A mom and a kid are lying on the bed.

The kid is **lying outside** and close to the other side of the bed.

The mom is **lying inside** and close to the wall.

The kid might **toss around** and roll off the bed.

In this situation, in Vietnamese, we often say "**the mom lies inside**" and "**the kid lies outside**".

I am not sure how to say it in English.  Here is my attempt: "**The mom should lie outside and the little kid inside because the kid often tosses around in his sleep and fall off the bed**"

Is my attempt correct?

Comment: I would understand 'inside' as 'the side against the wall', but I couldn't find much evidence online except for [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/143648/i-sleep-in-middle-you-sleep-in-outside-mummy-sleeps-in-inside/143654)

Comment: ...but it would be better to say _on the outside/inside_, because _outside/inside the bed_ would mean _on top of/under the bedclothes_.

Comment: *The mom should **lie / lay / be on the** outside and the little kid [**on the**] inside, because the kid often tosses around in his sleep and **could / might** fall off the bed*.

Comment: The end of the bed is against the wall, so is one side of it. [**falls off the bed**]

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Lay? surely not! She isn't laying eggs!

Comment: @KateBunting: I did think about that before deciding to include it anyway. Truth be told, I actually wrote ***lay*** first in my "list of three" before clicking on "Add comment" - but I downgraded it to second position because I thought some people might object (a half-hearted attempt to "hide" it! :). Personally, I don't particularly care about the ***lay / lie*** distinction anyway. For me, it's primarily just another bit of historical trivia on a par with ***who / whom***.

Comment: Ohmgeez Tom. Just say the child should sleep closest to the wall so he doesn't roll off the bed. Everyone can figure out that mom will take up the remaining space.

Answer (score 2):

"Outside" and "inside" is odd, when the alternative "next to the wall" is available.

"The mom" is odd phrasing.

The redundancy of "and the kid inside" could be cut.

There is grammatical inconsistency in the use of "[he] often tosses and fall".  Do you mean he "often fall**s**" or "he often tosses and may fall"

So my version would be

> The kid should sleep next to the wall so he doesn't fall off the bed.